# How to modify the value of nrank when plotting the envelope for an mppm object in spatstat?

Tags: r, spatstat

My object `model` is an `mppm` object obtained by fitting a model on several independent datasets using the `mppm` function from the `R` package `spatstat`.

Since the `envelope` function does not accept inputs of type `mppm`, I used the following code (see question [Plot an envelope for an mppm object in spatstat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286805/plot-an-envelope-for-an-mppm-object-in-spatstat)) to study its envelope:

```
gamma= 1 - 0.95^(1/3)
nsims=round(1/gamma-1)
sims <- simulate(model, nsim=2*nsims)
SIMS <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(sims)) SIMS[[i]] <- as.solist(sims[i,,drop=TRUE])
Hplus <- cbind(data, hyperframe(Sims=SIMS))

EE <- with(Hplus, envelope(Points, Kcross.inhom,funargs=list("A","A"), nsim=nsims, simulate=Sims,savefuns=TRUE,nrank = 1))

plot(pool(EE), main="A to A interactions")
```

However, it appears that the value of the parameter `nrank` has no effect on the final result (same goes, for instance, for the value of `nSD`). But setting `VARIANCE` to True does modify the result. How can I choose the rank of the envelope when working with an `mppm` object ?

Comment: This example cannot be reproduced because `model` is not defined. Please edit the example to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `mppm`.

After the second last line is executed, `EE` is a list of envelope objects . These objects have been correctly computed using the value of `nrank` that you specified.

The problem is that in the last line, the `pool` command did not respect the values of `nrank` used in these envelopes. That is a bug, which I will fix.

In the meantime, the following code will give you what you want:

```
Epool <- pool(EE, savefuns=TRUE)
Epool2 <- envelope(Epool, nrank=2)
```

Here the first line gathers all the simulated functions from all the envelopes in `EE`, and constructs a single, pooled envelope object from them, which also contains all those simulated functions. The second line uses the `envelope.envelope` to recompute the envelope limits using the saved functions and specifying `nrank=2`.